# weighted quick union with compression not faster than without it

Tags: c, algorithm

im reading a book named "Algorithms in C" by Robert Sdgewick and it stated there
among other sources that the weighted quick union with path compression is more efficient than without.
i wrote some code in order to see this in action so first i created alot of random numbers in a file:

```
    /* random number generator */
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      unsigned long long int a,b,i;
      FILE * file = fopen("exer", "w+");
      srand((unsigned) time(0));
      for (i = 0; i < 400000; i++) {
        a = (unsigned)rand() % 400000;
        b = (unsigned)rand() % 400000;
        fprintf(file, "%lld-%lld\n", a,b);
      }

  return 0;
}
```

then using the file as input to the algorithms

```
    /* WEIGHTED QUICK UNION WITH HALVING ALGORITHM */

#include <stdio.h>

#define N 400000

int main(void)
{
  unsigned long long int p, q, i, j, id[N], sz[N];

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      id[i] = i;
      sz[i] = 1;
    }
  FILE * file = fopen("exer", "r");

  while (fscanf(file, "%lld-%lld", &p, &q ) != -1) {
    for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i])
      id[i] = id[id[i]];
    for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j])
      id[j] = id[id[j]];
    if (i == j)
      continue;
    if (sz[i] < sz[j])
     {
      id[i] = j;
      sz[j] += sz[i];
    }
    else {
      id[j] = i;
      sz[i] += sz[j];
    }
    printf(" %lld %lld\n", p, q);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
/* WEIGHTED QUICK UNION ALGORITHM */

#include <stdio.h>

#define N 400000

int main(void)
{
  unsigned long long int p, q, i, j, id[N], sz[N];

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      id[i] = i;
      sz[i] = 1;
  }
  FILE * file = fopen("exer", "r");
  while(fscanf(file, "%lld-%lld", &p, &q) != -1) {
    for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);
    for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);
    if (i == j)
      continue;
    if (sz[i] < sz[j]) {
      id[i] = j;
      sz[j] += sz[i];
    }
    else {
      id[j] = i;
      sz[i] += sz[j];
    }
    printf(" %lld %lld\n", p, q);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

im running these programs with the time command and the results are showing
that the compression algortihm is not
more efficient than the without it
and sometime even slower

with path compression results:

```
real    0m0.898s
user    0m0.418s
sys     0m0.478s
```

without path compression results:

```
real    0m0.896s
user    0m0.436s
sys     0m0.458s
```

Comment: Hah - that indentation after `for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);`..

Comment: probably unrelated: `rand()` gives you a number between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, which is typically `32768`. So, if you expect numbers between `0` and `400 000`, the distribution is very bad.

Comment: This is normal. The gains of path compression are usually marginal.

Comment: @mch: It looks like `RAND_MAX` is 32767 with MSVC, but on Unix systems, which appears to be what OP has, it's more commonly 2147483647.

Comment: I agree with @YvesDaoust; the difference in asymptotic worst-case running times is driven by adversarial examples, which a random input of size N is not. I also wonder if most of the running time is I/O.